# java.lang.StackOverflowError when building Sencha/ ExtJS 5 project

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, extjs

When I open my project and Eclipse attempts to build it, I get this error: An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace". java.lang.StackOverflowError.

It still finishes building (I think), and I can proceed on. But I get an "Internal Error" popup saying that a stack overflow has occurred and that it's recommended that I exit the workbench. I just ignore the popup.

Here is my .log output:

```
!SESSION 2014-11-13 09:22:21.634 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data C:\Workspaces\pvmui-ws3

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-11-13 09:22:31.052
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-11-13 09:22:31.057
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\XXXXXX'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-11-13 09:24:25.196
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace".
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.vjet.dsf.jst.declaration.JstProxyType.getName(JstProxyType.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.vjet.dsf.jst.declaration.JstMixedType.getName(JstMixedType.java:75)
    **THESE TWO LINES REPEAT ABOUT 1023 TIMES**

!ENTRY org.eclipse.vjet.eclipse.core 4 0 2014-11-13 09:24:26.431
!MESSAGE There is no jst2dltk translator for node: org.eclipse.vjet.dsf.jst.term.ObjLiteral

!ENTRY org.eclipse.vjet.eclipse.core 4 0 2014-11-13 09:24:26.510
!MESSAGE There is no jst2dltk translator for node: org.eclipse.vjet.dsf.jst.term.ObjLiteral

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-11-13 09:24:27.036
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.vjet.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcut.run: {org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension$LaunchCommandHandler@6436afd6} vs {org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension$LaunchCommandHandler@42523e00}
```

What should I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JstMixedType](http://git.eclipse.org/c/vjet/org.eclipse.vjet.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.vjet.core.jst/src/org/eclipse/vjet/dsf/jst/declaration/JstMixedType.java) seems to accumulate multiple types and concatenates their names. In your case it contains itself (or a proxy around itself, exactly spoken). This should not happen. This seems to be a bug in the VJET core and should be [reported](http://eclipse.org/vjet/support/).

Possibly you can work around the bug by adapting your configuration/code. Do you have any mixed types which contain themselves? Is this intended? (it probably is) If no, change them.

Answer (score 0):

How to deal with the StackOverflowError:

The simplest solution is to carefully inspect the stack trace and detect the repeating pattern of line numbers. These line numbers indicate the code being recursively called. Once you detect these lines, you must carefully inspect your code and understand why the recursion never terminates.

---

If you have verified that the recursion is implemented correctly, you can increase the stack’s size, in order to allow a larger number of invocations. Depending on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) installed, the default thread stack size may equal to either 512KB, or 1MB. You can increase the thread stack size using the -Xss flag. This flag can be specified either via the project’s configuration, or via the command line. The format of the `-Xss` argument is:

```
-Xss<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]
```

By the way it seems a eclipse bug(Read this [ref](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407123)) which has been fixed in the latest version.